# C# telegram bot - need inline buttons to behave like / commands

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I am creating a telegram bot and am currently using / commands to navigate through the bots menus and options, however I would like to use inline buttons for a neater look. The help I’ve found online has helped me to print buttons to the chat but I cannot figure out how to use them to act in a similar way as the / commands do

for example a command I have is /Topup which when clicked takes you to the topup menu (another telegram message with more / commands, I would like an inline button with the text “Topup” to do the same job however I can’t figure out the callback methods. I am using Telegram.bot version 18.0.0 in C#

I realize in older versions of Telegram.bot you can add an event listener using += but with 18.0.0 I am using

Bot.StartReceiving(updatehandler etc etc